# igraph: scale plot size according to size of quartz window

Tags: r, plot, scale, igraph

I am using the igraph package in R. My problem is that, when plotting my network using the plot() function, it is not changing in size accordingly to when I change the size of the quartz window. Is there a parameter for this, e.g. similar to stretch="Fill" ?

Comment: I found the right parameter to use; asp=F

Comment: Oh, so it was changing in size, but it was keeping the aspect ratio (so that circles were still circle).

Comment: Thanks! I had this problem for a long time and did never think of such an easy solution!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to save your plot as SVG or PDF, then crop and resize using an editor such as Inkscape.

Comment: I've had sucess with this technique using pdfcrop that comes with the LaTeX suite

Answer (score 0):

Given the comment from the help file quoted here, my suspicion is that you are doing things that igraph is not intended for.
"*One convenient way to plot graphs is to plot with tkplot ﬁrst, handtune the placement of the
vertices, query the coordinates by the tkplot.getcoords function and use them with plot to plot
the graph to any R device.*"

Either set the quartz window size first, or don't use `igraph` to create your static plot.